# Slow result with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

I have a simple SQL query and if I limit more than 10, the time for the result exceeds 15 seconds. My question is, Why it's slow ? Here is my request:

```
SELECT E.ID_Pays
FROM tbl_Usager A
LEFT JOIN tbl_Ville B ON A.ID_Ville = B.ID_Ville
LEFT JOIN tbl_Departement C ON B.ID_Departement = C.ID_Departement
LEFT JOIN tbl_Pays E ON C.ID_Pays = E.ID_Pays 
WHERE E.ID_Pays='1'
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: Why are you selecting the column whose value will always be `'1'`?  Also, you don't provide enough information to explain a performance issue.  How big are the tables?  What are the indexes and primary keys?

Comment: Can you show the indexes available on each table.

Comment: I selected this column with '1 'only to reduce the request to the problem. The original request is much greater. Because even with the simplified application, my problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `left join`s are unnecessary for your query.  The `where` clause turns them into `inner join`s.

Second, the final join is unnecessary, because you can take the value from the `departement` table.

```
SELECT d.ID_Pays
FROM tbl_Usager u JOIN
     tbl_Ville v
     ON u.ID_Ville = v.ID_Ville JOIN
     tbl_Departement d
     ON v.ID_Departement = d.ID_Departement
WHERE d.ID_Pays = '1'
LIMIT 8;
```

That will help.  Next, I assume that all the `ID_*` variables are the primary keys in their respective tables.  Finally, create an index on `id_pays`:

```
create index idx_department_2 on tbl_department(id_pays, id_departement);
```

These should help the query.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to optimize the indexes management in all the tables, usually that's the problem.

Here's a link that may help you: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html